# Subclassing Observable

Tags: rx-java

I want to subclass an observable to create a observable with an extra function. The extra function will tell the caller of the observable has an active cache and will return immediately.

This is the use case that I want to achieve:

```
func fetchData():
    Observable observable = getObservable()
    if !observable.hasActiveCache():
        showLoading()

    observable.subscribe(subscriber)
```

So I only want to show the loading dialog if the observable will fetch data from the network.

I have tried subclassing observable (class MyObservable extends Observable) and it works in some cases. However, if somewhere in the chain someone does for example a map in the observable it seems to become a regular observable again.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Types are lost pretty fast in RxJava when using fluent operator calls. Your best option is to keep a reference to the original Observable with your custom functions and call it directly. (We have similar inconveniences with our GroupedObservables, Subjects and ConnectableObservables.)